# wrong zlib.dll added by pyinstaller to exe folder

Tags: python, pyinstaller, zlib

I'm trying to freeze my application using `pyInstaller`, unfortunately although my `.exe` file is created properly, when i'm trying to run the app, it's failed every time with `ImportError` of missing `dll` file without notify which one is missing as you can see below:

```
File "Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 396, i
n load_module
  File "site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 31, in <module>
  File "Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 396, i
n load_module
  File "site-packages\matplotlib\colorbar.py", line 36, in <module>
  File "Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 396, i
n load_module
  File "site-packages\matplotlib\contour.py", line 20, in <module>
  File "Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 396, i
n load_module
  File "site-packages\matplotlib\font_manager.py", line 55, in <module>
  File "Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 687, i
n load_module
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.
[5532] Failed to execute script Main
```

after some research i found out that the `dll` that cause the problem was `zlib.dll`, its seems that `pyInstaller` isn't collecting the right `zlib.dll` because when i have tried to add `zlib.dll` from `\my\path\to\anaconda\Library\bin` by hand to the `.exe` folder, my app ran perfect.

I'm using `Python=2.7`, `Anaconda=5.2.0`, `pyInstaller=3.3.1`.

Comment: I have had a similar issue.  I'm getting: `libz.so.1: version ZLIB_1.2.9 not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng16.so.16)` on Linux, but it has something to do with different Ubuntu versions.  I'm wondering if more carefully specifying the zlib dependency will allow mine to work.  If you got yours working, it would be great to post an answer and maybe we can learn from your experience!